# How to live code in .NET Core 3.1 application while using IIS server?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, web-hosting

Recently I reinstalled my PC. **I had my project hosted on IIS server**, I remember that in Visual Studio I had to prepare IIS profile in debug options with hosting model `OutOfProcess` and then when I made some changes in code and hit refresh button in browser, **project was automatically recompiling and giving me new results.** It was basically live coding.

Ofc just refreshing page without any changes in code didn't trigger recompiling and browsing project was smooth.

I have no idea how did I achieve that, I was looking through internet for a while and coulnd't find solution. Every solution I found says to use `dotnet watch run`.

Right now I have same setup and it kinda works, but I have to hit compile every time I change something in order to see results on web which is really annoying.

**Any idea how to achieve live coding with IIS?**

EDIT:
I found the option I was looking for, but seems like it is set correctly and refresh doesn't trigger an rebuild.
[image: Autobuild on broswer request]

Answer (score 0):

I found partial solution, when I select:

[image: Browse With...]

Or:

[image: View in Browser]

It does work, however I think before it was working automaticaly without triggering an browser from VS. I'd appreciate any solution without it, however it is good enough for now.